# Show url display in bottom-left by JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

Is there any trick to displaying url on bottom left of page by **Javascript** ?

[image]

**Example my link element is :**

```
<div data-link="http://stackoverflow.com"></div>
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).on('click','[data-link]',function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('data-link');
    window.open(url,'_blank');
}).on('mouseover','[data-link]',function(){
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = $(this).attr('data-link');
    $(a).trigger('mouseover');
    // Nothing showing
});
```

Possible ? Any trick ?

Comment: you talk about jQuery here, and what you actually want to do is a bit unclear ... at mouse hovering you want to display a link ? Or you want to generate a link a mouse hovering on a div ? because the JS example seems weird. Why would you trigger an additionnal "mouseover" event ?

Comment: @Alex Ok. Im edited to my rest code. I just want to display url on bottom-left of the page (if possible)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not possible with Javascript, this is a browser-specific function that only triggers when your mouse hovers over a link. If you trigger the .hover() with JS, it "only" applies the CSS-Rules and fires the JS-Functions.

You could create an absolute positioned div with the link-tag and show this when you hover over an element, but it could cause problems when you hover over an actual A-Tag, then your div will get hidden under the browser-field.

Comment: This was what i think about hidden link element. But I think its not so good (I dont like) . But thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('a').mouseover(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var style = "position: fixed; left: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 1000000;";
    $('body').append("<b id='urlDisplay' style='" + style + "'>" + url + "</b>");
});
$('a').mouseout(function() { $('#urlDisplay').remove(); });
```

Make it prettier by putting the css elsewhere!

Comment: hmmm, Thanks. But im looking for native url display :D

Comment: why if i may ask? you can certainly style it so it looks native.

Comment: nahhh, i just was wondering if there possible. + i dont want to use time for styling for all browsers :D

Comment: its not all browsers that do this anyway. afaik its only chrome doing it